# MySQL SELECT column FROM table WHERE column IS NULL

Tags: mysql, null

This is not working for me, using `Toad` for `MySQL`. I'm using `MySQL 5.5` from `XAMPP 1.83` on Windows.

I have a table with column `InstitutionState` defined as `VARCHAR(20)`. Some rows appear to have this column "empty", meaning `LENGTH(InstitutionState) = 0`.

If I `SELECT ... WHERE InstitutionState IS NULL`, I get no rows.

If I `SELECT ... WHERE InstitutionState = ''`, It works. Why is this?

Here's sample data.

```
mysql> select InstitutionState, ISNULL(InstitutionState), length(InstitutionState)
    ->   from institution;
+----------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| InstitutionState     | ISNULL(InstitutionState) | length(InstitutionState) |
+----------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| NY                   |                        0 |                        2 |
| NY                   |                        0 |                        2 |
| NY                   |                        0 |                        2 |
| IL                   |                        0 |                        2 |
| NC                   |                        0 |                        2 |
| TX                   |                        0 |                        2 |
| DC                   |                        0 |                        2 |
| NY                   |                        0 |                        2 |
| CA                   |                        0 |                        2 |
|                      |                        0 |                        0 |
| KS                   |                        0 |                        2 |
|                      |                        0 |                        0 |
| NY                   |                        0 |                        2 |
| ND                   |                        0 |                        2 |
| PA                   |                        0 |                        2 |
| WI                   |                        0 |                        2 |
| PA                   |                        0 |                        2 |
| MD                   |                        0 |                        2 |
| IN                   |                        0 |                        2 |
| PA                   |                        0 |                        2 |
| NE                   |                        0 |                        2 |
| ID                   |                        0 |                        2 |
| CA                   |                        0 |                        2 |
|                      |                        0 |                        0 |
| FL                   |                        0 |                        2 |
| MO                   |                        0 |                        2 |
|                      |                        0 |                        0 |
| OH                   |                        0 |                        2 |
| IL                   |                        0 |                        2 |
| OH                   |                        0 |                        2 |
```

Comment: Er, because `NULL` is not the same as `''` !

Comment: Unless you're using Oracle..  Sigh.

Comment: cause you have empty string("") as column values not NULL, NULL means no values all at(value not defined)

Comment: @esdebon No. But Oracle Corp. does own MySQL

Comment: And it's only in Oracle for legacy reasons, since they've had that behavior since before there was a SQL standard.

Comment: @Strawberry Oracle the owner =>  Oracle  ==  MySQL ????

Comment: @esdebon Oracle acquired MySQL only (fairly) recently

Comment: I admit that I am Oracle-centric. The behavior on Oracle is consistent. NULL means unknown, and you cannot use = or != to test for NULL. The problem I'm seeing with MySQL is that the MyISAM and InnoDB engines treat an empty string and NULL differently WHEN INSERTING or updating a column value. So there is no single way to test for an empty string or NULL (which I personally consider to mean the same thing). You must use two tests--  = '' OR IS NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually, `NULL` means **“a missing unknown value”**

OR

`NULL` means *no data, emptiness, nothing, unknown, missing value, etc*. The value empty string means an empty string.

- *Confusing the `NULL` value and the empty string may cause data integrity problem.*

What `NULL` means in the context of a relational database is that the pointer to the character field is set to `0x00` in the row's header, therefore no data to access.

- `NULL` and `''` take up the exact same number of bytes on the disk.

Hence, there is no space savings.

- You can add an index on a column that can have `NULL` values. Otherwise, you must declare an indexed column `NOT NULL`, and you cannot insert `NULL` into the column.

Furthermore, allowing `NULL` is a less restrictive configuration than disallowing `NULL`. It only follows that if any entity integrity issues are to arise, it would be from FEWER checks that the data are sound. Therefore, logically, allowing NULL should always have a good, solid reason, and disallowing NULL is a good practice.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO ... (InstitutionState) VALUES (NULL);

mysql> INSERT INTO ... (InstitutionState) VALUES ('');
```

Both statements will insert a value into the InstitutionState column, but the first inserts a `NULL` value and the second inserts an empty string. The meaning of the first can be regarded as “InstitutionState is not known” and the meaning of the second can be regarded as “the Institution is known to have no state, and thus no InstitutionState.”

To search for column values that are `NULL`, you cannot use an `expr = NULL` test. The following statement returns no rows, because expr = NULL is never true for any expression:

```
mysql> SELECT ... WHERE InstitutionState = NULL;
```

To look for `NULL` values, you must use the `IS NULL` test. The following statements show how to find the `NULL` InstitutionState and the empty InstitutionState:

```
mysql> SELECT ... WHERE InstitutionState IS NULL;

mysql> SELECT ... WHERE InstitutionState = '';
```

---

```
mysql> SELECT 1 IS NULL, 1 IS NOT NULL;

+-----------+---------------+
| 1 IS NULL | 1 IS NOT NULL |
+-----------+---------------+
|         0 |             1 |
+-----------+---------------+
```

You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to test for NULL. To demonstrate this for yourself, try the following query:

```
mysql> SELECT 1 = NULL, 1 <> NULL, 1 < NULL, 1 > NULL;

+----------+-----------+----------+----------+
| 1 = NULL | 1 <> NULL | 1 < NULL | 1 > NULL |
+----------+-----------+----------+----------+
|     NULL |      NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
+----------+-----------+----------+----------+
```

In addition,

- In *MyISAM MYSQL you save one bit per row not using NULL*.
- [While a NULL itself does not require any storage space, NDBCLUSTER reserves 4 bytes per row if the table definition contains any columns defined as NULL, up to 32 NULL columns. (If a MySQL Cluster table is defined with more than 32 NULL columns up to 64 NULL columns, then 8 bytes per row is reserved.)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-requirements.html)
- It also makes the database work faster.

To get `''` AND `NULL`s,

We would use:

```
 SELECT ... WHERE IFNULL(InstitutionState , '') = '';
```

Which says if the field is `NULL` pretend that it is an empty string i.e. `''`.

Comment: >IFNULL(InstitutionState , '') = ''

That is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `NULL` value isn't an *actual* value in SQL, but the lack of a value.  One can think of it as *unknown*.  For that reason, not even `NULL` is equal to *another null*.

Null values are actually implemented as a bitmask on the row, which indicate which columns have null values.  So, these values aren't even stored on the heap table in the same way as other values, which is one of the reasons why you have to explicitly declare a column as *nullable*.

The string `''` *is* actually known.  It's *known* to be `''`.  This isn't `null`, nor is that *null bit* set on the tuple.

For this reason, querying for rows where a column `IS NULL` will *not* return rows with a value of `''` nor will querying for rows where a column is `''` return null values.  They are two completely different things.

There are actually a *few* exceptions.  For example, in Oracle, any reference to `''` will be *implicitly cast* to `NULL`.  This behavior was implemented back in the 80s before a real SQL standard, so Oracle has had to maintain it for backwards compatibility reasons.

Comment: @Strawberry - I think `NULL == NULL` resolves to `NULL`, which makes sense.  "Is this unknown equal to that unknown?" - "I don't know!"

Comment: Mike, I'm having to reconsider my Oracle-centric position that null and an empty string should mean the same thing. If you have a numeric column that holds a quantity, then NULL should mean unknown while 0 means zero. I think an empty string is the character-equivalent of a numerical zero. For example, a middle name field (I have no middle name) if NULL means the middle name is unknown, while set to an empty string, means there is none (hence, numerical 0). BUT, I don't know how you could distinguish NULL from empty when the data is coming from a field on a webpage.