# Select rows that contain only null values within a column, for a non-primary key id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

| Number | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 1 | Null |
| 2 | Null |

I would only want "2" to return.

This query was my closest success, where I was trying to just find any values that would account for my criteria, but this did not return values that only contained nulls in the `Name` column.

```
select top 1000 
    Number, Name, 
    case 
        when count(name) over (partition by number) = 0 
            then 'y' 
    end as valid 
from 
    Numbers n
group by 
    Number, Name
order by 
    case 
        when count(name) over (partition by Number) = 0 
            then 'y' 
    end desc, Number desc
```

I have tried the answers in the following stack overflow questions without success:

[how to select rows with no null values (in any column) in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67076546/how-to-select-rows-with-no-null-values-in-any-column-in-sql)

[Query for checking if every cell is null in a column by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75089487/query-for-checking-if-every-cell-is-null-in-a-column-by-id)

[MySQL SELECT column FROM table WHERE column IS NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074740/mysql-select-column-from-table-where-column-is-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get those numbers that appear only with `NULL` values in the `name` column, we can use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`.

Since `COUNT` ignores `NULL` values, we can simply check whether any name occurs per number.

So we put this condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT 
  number
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY 
  number
HAVING 
  COUNT(name) = 0
ORDER BY
  number;
```

If you rather want all rows, not only the "NULL-only" numbers and then add a flag that shows if a number appears with `NULL` values only, it's a bit more complicated.

In this case, I recommend to remove the `GROUP BY` clause and use a windowed `COUNT`:

```
SELECT
  number, 
  name,
  CASE WHEN COUNT(name) OVER(PARTITION BY number) = 0
    THEN 'y'
    ELSE 'n' END AS flag_only_nulls
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY
  number,
  name;
```

And if the result should be sorted by that flag (for example to show the "NULL-only" rows first), then repeat the `CASE` expression in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT
  number, 
  name,
  CASE WHEN COUNT(name) OVER(PARTITION BY number) = 0
    THEN 'y'
    ELSE 'n' END AS flag_only_nulls
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN COUNT(name) OVER(PARTITION BY number) = 0
    THEN 0
    ELSE 1 END,
  number,
  name;
```

Switch 0 and 1 at the end of the `CASE` expression to rather show the "Null-only" rows at the end.
Note that sometimes using functions and `CASE` expressions within the `ORDER BY` clause can slow down the query. If you encounter this problem, it might be faster to use a `CTE` instead:

```
WITH sub AS
(SELECT
  number, 
  name,
  CASE WHEN COUNT(name) OVER(PARTITION BY number) = 0
    THEN 'y'
    ELSE 'n' END AS flag_only_nulls
FROM yourtable)
SELECT 
  number,
  name,
  flag_only_nulls
FROM sub
  ORDER BY flag_only_nulls;
```

See this [sample fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/p2NK8PAg) with your data and some other rows.